# Using Ruby on share web hosts

Tags: wordpress, ruby

We are developing a Wordpress theme and we are going to publish it on themeforest.com. We are using Sass(scss Syntax) as our CSS Preprocessor and we need to compile it on server side.

We have two solutions:

- Use [phpsass](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass) which is a php script(but it has some bugs)
- Use Ruby Compiler which most of [wordpress plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/sass) use this

I noticed that plugins which use Ruby need to have PHP proc_open function enabled on server.

My question is what are Pros and Cons of using Ruby compiler on servers? and are most of shared web hosts support Ruby and have PHP proc_open function enabled by default?

Comment: I think phpsass is more preferable, fix bugs if it harms your code and use it

Comment: I found a php library that support all features without bug: leafo.net/scssphp I decide to use it and forget ruby compiler for php user!